# Recovering failed RAID5

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid, md

```
md0 : active raid5 sdc2[5](S) sda2[4] sdd2[3](F) sdb2[1]
      17510688768 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/2] [UU__]
```

What happend:

1. sdc failed
2. I have repleaced it with a new HDD
3. Recovery stopped with some bad sectors on sdd

What I want to do is to recover as much data as possible and lose only files that are stored in bad sectors, not the whole raid.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

- Stop the resynchronisation
- Erase the RAID superblock from the new disk
- Use `dd_rescue` to replicate the second failing drive to the new one
- Replace this second failing one with its duplicate. If you've copied it correctly then when you restart the RAID it shouldn't notice
- Copy off all the data you can, bearing in mind that there's still no RAID 5 parity because you're running in degraded mode, and that some of the files may have undetectable data errors, as might the filesystem
- Rebuild the RAID array with a missing disk, recreate the filesystem
- Copy back your validated saved data
- Purchase a second replacement disk and add it to the rebuilt array